# Simulate pin behaviour based on PulseView recording

Tags: testing, platformio

I have a bunch of PulseView recordings from an existing device. Currently to verify if my Arduino handles the input properly I always use the real device. However it would be great if I could somehow test my code with existing recordings. I am using platform.io. Perhaps there is some test framework that can mock a pin based on a recording? For example when I start the test, pin 8 should be high for 10μs then low for 7 and so on. Is there some framework to mock such things?

Comment: that is not an arduino specific question ... it applies to any microcontroller ... if you are talking about a hardware solution, then ask at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard of such a test framework and I doubt there is one, at least for hobbyists. Such a framework would need to include a lot of hardware to accommodate all the possible electrical test cases and also a rather complex software to control the hardware according to user input. So it is not really practical to have a general testing framework.

But you can build your own for your specific case. Using another Arduino and outputting the requested pulses should not be too difficult. In the simplest version just some `digitalWrite()`s and some `delayMicroseconds()` calls.